# Get updated polygon points after transformation

Tags: c#, wpf, transform, polygon, shapes

I need to retrieve the new points coordinates of my a polygon(inside a canvas) after a RotateTransform.

```
RotateTransform rotation = new RotateTransform(rotationAngle);
polygon.RenderTransform = rotation;
```

As the RenderTransform is applied, the `polygon.Points` collection doesn't get the new values.

I've read about people trying to bind this `PointCollection` (that are not an `ObservableCollection`), but I didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may get the transformed points by sequentially applying the transform to all points in the Polygon's `Points` collection:

```
using System.Linq;

var transformedPoints = polygon.Points.Select(p => rotation.Transform(p));
```